# Ferry's Black Body

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

Why is the hole considered as the actual black body in Ferry's enclosure?
Why is there a need of double- walled enclosure? These are two separate questions referring to Ferry's black body.

Answer (score 1):

A blackbody has a spectrum which depends only on temperature. The easiest way to achieve this is to have an object where the light only comes from scattering of black material at a uniform temperature.

The Ferry black body is designed so no ray coming in from the outside can get out again - so if you have a reflection of eg sunlight you don't get any sunlight out.

The inside surface should be black, although if you have enough reflections, so that all of any incident light is absorbed the spectrum will be blackbody whatever the surface.  Soot works well because the microscopic structure has lots of small cavities that absorb, re-emit and scatter light.

The dual wall is so that the inside is at a uniform temperature even if different parts of the outside are seeing different sources of heat